# Listening to menu opening

Tags: android, focus, popupmenu, optionmenu

I have a `RelativeLayout`. In that I create several `ToggleButton` views. The user can set those ToggleButtons on and off.

When the user opens the Activity's `OptionMenu` I want all those ToggleButtons to become OFF. To do this I am setting programmatically the ToggleButtons to OFF in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` code.

I have also a `PopupMenu` registered to a `Imagebutton`. I want also when the users opens the `PopupMenu` by clicking the `Imagebutton` all the ToggleButtons to become OFF. So, I am turning the togglebuttons to off in the Imagebutton's `setOnClickListener` code.

My issue is that the updates to the Togglebuttons' state (to Off) are shown only after the `OptionsMenu` or the `PopupMenu` is closed. Instead I want all the ToggleButtons become Off as soon the user opens the menus. I thought I have to use some `OnFocusChangeListener` on some view. I tried to use it on the Activity's top layout but it doesn't work.

How could I get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself by overriding the `onWindowFocusChanged` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus) {
        //code to turn off togglebuttons goes here 
    }
}
```